# Toggle property of an element inside an array VueJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a text field in which you can input the field and `on Click` it adds a value to an array which renders the chips. Now each chips has a `value` property and a `toggle` property. By Default every new chip has `toggle` set to `false`. Now i can add as well as delete chips. The chips are deleted by using the `deleteChips` method. What i am trying to do is when there is only one chip left, the chip's `toggle` value should change dynamically to `false` or `true` depending on whatever it was at the time. So basically `toggle = !toggle`.

I have tried using the `array.length` but wasn't able to get it working.

Here is a sample [pen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/vYNXjdE?editors=1011)

Here is the sample code:-

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      inputValue: "",
      inputArray: [],
      selectedChip: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    createChips() {
      this.inputArray.unshift({
        value: this.inputValue,
        toggle: false
      });
      this.inputValue = "";
    },
    deleteChips(chip) {
      let index = this.inputArray.filter((el) => el.chip === chip);
      this.inputArray.splice(index, 1);
    },
    chipSelection(item) {
      this.selectedChip = item;
    },
    toggleChip(item) {
      item.toggle = true;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout justify-center>
        <v-flex xs6>
          <v-text-field v-model="inputValue"></v-text-field>
          <v-btn @click="createChips">Click Me</v-btn>
          <div v-if="inputArray.length > 0">
            <div v-for="chip in inputArray">
              <v-chip :key="chip.value" close @click="chipSelection(chip.value)" @input=deleteChips(chip)>
                <v-avatar>
                  <v-icon @click="toggleChip(chip.value)">
                    account_circle
                  </v-icon>
                </v-avatar>
                <span v-if="selectedChip === chip.value">{{chip.value}}</span>
              </v-chip>
            </div>
          </div>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but the `v-if="inputArray.length > 0"` `<div />` is unnecessary since it wraps the `v-for`

Comment: If your intent is to toggle the `.toggle` property, why do you only set it to be `true`? Wouldn't you want `item.toggle = !item.toggle` instead?

Comment: yeah you're right, it's something i was working on and brought it along i guess.

Comment: Yes and no because right now it is happening only on the one that i have clicked. Instead when there is only one element left in array, i want that to happen on the last element without me clicking on it first.

Comment: So as soon as i delete the second last element, the last element's property should be set to `toggle = !toggle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tbh, I can't really follow your intent, but based on the comments, perhaps you want to watch the `inputArray` and execute code based on changes to its length.

```
watch: {
    inputArray(newValue, oldValue) {
        if ((newValue.length !== oldValue.length) && (newValue.length === 1)) {
            this.inputArray[0].toggle = !this.inputArray[0].toggle;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting. I am not very much familiar with watchers. Could you please explain how to execute these? Would i need to call them somehow like on onclick or are they more like direct functions in javascript?

Comment: btw thank you. i got almost the same result by using computed.